# Optional assignment in Swift not working?

Tags: swift

For some reason I can't get optionals working in Swift. They seem to always be `nil`. Either there's a bug somewhere, or I don't understand how optionals work. Here's what I'm doing:

First, I open up a Swift REPL: `/Applications/Xcode6-Beta2.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/swift`

Here's what I enter in the REPL (combined with return values):

```
1> var perhapsInt: Int?
perhapsInt: Int? = nil
2> perhapsInt = 1
3> if let actualInt = perhapsInt {
4.     println("here")
5. }
6> perhapsInt
$R2: Int? = nil
```

`"here"` never gets printed, because `let actualInt = perhapsInt` evaluates to false, because the line `perhapsInt = 1` is doing absolutely nothing, so `perphapsInt` retains its value of `nil`.

The same occurs if I set `perhapsInt` to a value during initialization:

```
1> var perhapsInt: Int? = 5
perhapsInt: Int? = 5
2> perhapsInt
$R1: Int? = nil
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This looks like a bug in the Swift REPL. You should [file a Radar](http://bugreport.apple.com).

This snippet works just fine for me inside an Xcode playground:

```
var perhapsInt: Int?                  // nil
perhapsInt = 1                        // {Some 1}

if let actualInt = perhapsInt {
    actualInt                         // 1
}
```

Comment: Just checked and it works for me inside an Xcode Playground, too. I'll file a bug report.

Comment: Yeah. It works if you move the code inside a function in the REPL, too, and call it. Definitely looks buggy to me.